# Consumption of different type of energy when one is inactive

Tags: biochemistry, proteins, health, fat-metabolism

I'm wonder if there is any study done on this and what are the results?
how much of each type of energy one's body(healthy normal person) uses when inactive(seating down)

I know there are alot of dependencies, but any kind of ball park answer will be great.

ps: when I say type of energy, I mean: fat, carb, protein.

Comment: Simple google search gave [this](http://www.myvmc.com/lifestyles/energy-expenditure-how-the-body-burns-calories/) ! Good enough to answer your question.

Comment: Thank you for this link, but it doesn't provide me with any precise numbers I'm looking for.